# Control going inside 'If' block even when it should not (only for 1 value)

Tags: apex, date, customization, conditional, if

I am trying to count the number of weekdays (Monday - Friday) by taking the number of days since 01-07-1900 (7th January, 1900), for a given date, and checking the modulus by 7.
For modulus values 0 - 5, it's working fine, but for value = 6 (for Saturday), it's not evaluating.

For the given code snippet, for the variable, `dayValueInInteger` - it evaluates correctly for 0 - 5 but when we compare the variable with value = 6, it is somehow not evaluating.

Please find code snippet and debug attachment.

```
Date tempDate;
if(monthVar == 1||monthVar == 2){
    tempDate = Date.newInstance(fyEnd.year(), monthVar, i);
}
else{
    tempDate = Date.newInstance(fyStart.year(), monthVar, i);
}

// calculating difference here
Integer dayValueInInteger = Math.mod(tempDate.daysBetween(Date.newInstance(1900, 1, 7)), 7);

// checking whether the value is a weekday or not
if(dayValueInInteger != 0 && dayValueInInteger != 6){
    system.debug('---inside if--and value of dayValueInInteger---'+dayValueInInteger);
    freeDaysInMonth.add(i);
}
```

[image: Debug log screenshot]

Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in the code. To notice that, look at the debug which is printing 4 `-` characters even through you have 3 in your debug at `dayValueInInteger*---*`.

```
system.debug('---inside if--and value of dayValueInInteger---'+dayValueInInteger);
```

The `daysBetween` is subtracting your date from the past date and the result is negative. Since there is no negative for 0*, the code works.

When the value is 6 (actually it is `-6`) it enters the `if` as the condition is satisfied.

> Datebetween:  Returns the number of days between the Date that called
>   the method and the specified date.

It should be

```
Date knownSunday = Date.newInstance(1900, 1, 7);
Integer dayValueInInteger = Math.mod(knownSunday.daysBetween(tempDate), 7);
```